# The toilet is clogged with dirty water

Tags: water, bathroom

Yesterday we saw that water is going slowly and there is dirty water left.

We poured hot water and try shirt hanger but nothing changed. Is there any practical way before calling a technician or Mario Bros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I watched many youtube videos about solving my problem and could not find place to sell me the tools like suggested here and in videos , also  it is the first time something happened like this in my house. So I 
after my search I decided to buy a gel to recover my problem.

It took me 3 minutes to solve my problem without involving with any dirty water and buying any tool that I will probably took place in my house.

I just pour 2 litres of hot water in my sink then pour the chemical just in two minutes i started to hear some noises like melody. Water was going as like as first day.

Thanks for your kind replies.

[image: BATHROOM DRAIN GEL]

Comment: While this works, there are two major issues. One is that, if one lives in a rented home, use of caustic chemicals may be prohibited by the lease. The other is that, if this does not dislodge the clog (which does happen), it has become more dangerous to remove the clog due, again, to the caustic nature of these chemicals.

Comment: yes you are right, using chemicals are dangerous , I am always prefer to use a method without chemicals but we have to admit that sometimes only  chemicals solve the problem and yes we should use with our own risk.

Answer (score 4):

My past experience (prior to low-flow toilets, don't know if this would work with those) is that you can usually correct this problem by clogging the toilet more.  Put several wads of toilet paper into the bowl, and make a "slow flush" -- lift the lid on the tank, reach into the water there (which is clean), and lift the flush valve just a crack, to let the bowl fill slowly.  When the water in the bowl is just below the rim (and the paper wads have finished clogging the trap), push the flush valve back down to close it.

Once this is done, use and ordinary plunger, emphasizing the push stroke over the pull -- this will push the paper wads against the partial clog, and usually push it on around the curve of the trap.  Once the water in the bowl begins to flow normally, let it finish cycling (and the tank finish refilling), then flush one more time.  Everything should be back to normal, and no special tools needed.

Comment: I don't have any plunger and saw the  last one at early 80's.  I tried clogging many times but nothing changed so far. I didn't try the trap thing yet;  I will  check it.

Comment: Without a plunger to push the artificial clog, you can't develop enough force to move the original one.  Plungers are cheap -- under $10 and sold in grocery stores in the US.  And once you have one, you'll have it; like any other tool, it isn't a single use device.

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself a toilet snake.  They consist of a long, spring like cable with a slightly larger end with an 'auger' type point.  Mine has a plastic housing which holds about 3 - 5 feet of this spring and then 'feeds' it out as you rotate a handle.

To start you uncoil about 12 - 18 inches and work it down the drain and past the toilet bend.  Then you rotate the spring while feeding more out and down into the drain.  With some luck and patience, you should be able to dislodge the clog.

Example of tool I used: 
[image]